# PHP file path not found when I have JavaScript run a PHP script with XMLHTTPREQUEST (404 error); what to do?

Tags: javascript, php, xml, spring, spring-mvc

When I hit the button on the UI to have the JS communicate with PHP to pull up a "Hello world" page, I am getting a **"{"timestamp":"2021-06-10T20:14:59.671+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"","path":"/hello.php"}"** in the browser.

In the Eclipse console, it says: **2021-06-10 16:52:27.193  WARN 16688 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": projectname/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.php]**

What do I do? Here's some code I have, and I have tried many file path formats where I refer to the PHP file. But it's all the same error!

Here's some of my code:

**JSP page (just the Javascript part of it):**

```
<button onclick=refreshData()>Say Hello</button>
  <div id="content" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshData(){
      var display = document.getElementById("content");
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "hello.php");
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlhttp.send();
      
 
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
          display.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        } else {
          display.innerHTML = "Loading...";
        };
      }
    }
  </script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
print "<p>Hello World</p>";
?>
```

This is in Spring MVC using Eclipse. I have the JavaScript on a JSP file page. What do I do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: With a relative URL (just "hello.php"), the browser will try to load it from the same host and port combination. In this case, that's your Spring MVC app. It is very unlikely that your Spring app can parse PHP code. It needs an Apache, Nginx or similar webserver running alongside Spring/Tomcat, which is probably running on a different port number. You need to use the full url, for example `http://localhost:8080/hello.php` if Apache/Nginx is listening on port 8080. Unless you're using a reverse proxy or something.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I've tried that too, but to no avail. Any other ideas? I've tried many different kinds of file paths.   I don't technically have anything mapped to "/hello.php". Is that why it doesn't work?     Do I need to map something in the java controller class to "/hello.php"?     When I replace "hello.php" with the localhost:8080 link + /mapped_page, it somewhat comes alive and does things that this mapped page is told to do in the controller class (when I changed the link in a different scenario of calling a php script from JS).

Comment: Do you have an Apache or Nginx server running for your PHP code? That is, if you pretend your Spring app does not exist and you just want to test your PHP code, how would you request it?

Answer (score -1):

I always use:

```
 $('#content').load("hello.php");
```

Just be sure your .php file is in the same folder

Comment: This is irrelevant, the problem is that OP does not know what to put in `.load("<here>")`. Switching from plain javascript to jQuery will not solve the issue.